# What's the best command to use to change a timestamp to readable date when 'tail -f'-ing a log file?

Tags: shell, script, pipe, awk, timestamp

I have a program which logs like this:

**1324218770.7644** INFO etc

What's the best Linux shell program to pipe that through to change the timestamps to a human readable format like **Sun 18 Dec 2011 15:32:50** CET?

I can pipe like this through

```
| cut -f 1 -d\   | awk '{print strftime("%c",$1)}'
```

for the timestamps only, but how do I maintain the rest of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just override `$1`, then print all line

```
$ echo '1324218770.7644 INFO etc' | awk '{$1=strftime("%c", $1); print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want the date to be changed inline, printing the rest of the line as well.  Try replacing field 1 with the output of `strftime()`.

```
$ echo "1234218770.7644 INFO etc' | awk '{$1=strftime("%c", $1); print}'
Mon 09 Feb 2009 05:32:50 PM EST INFO etc
```

Comment: %s gives me the timestamp - Maybe's its an awk version thing.

Comment: Nope.  Meant to type `%c` when I copied from the terminal.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: How did you get the output? Your quotes are kinda messed up in the `echo` statement.